# Boto S3 Key MD5 property not stored with key

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I may have this wrong but I'm under the impression that when I use the `set_contents_from_filename` method, the MD5 hash of the file should be automatically calculated and stored as metadata with the key.  Thus, when comparing files for possible overwriting, one only has to download the MD5 property of the key to compare with the local file's hash.  However, even though I can successfully upload files as keys, the MD5 property of the keys is always `None`.  Why?  Please see code example below.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key

key = 'xxxx'
secret = 'xxxx'
connection = S3Connection(key, secret)
bucket = connection.get_bucket('xxxx')

# create a file and push it to S3
f = open('test_file.txt', 'rwb')
f.write('this is a test')
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'test_key'
k.set_contents_from_file(f)
# check MD5
k.md5
>>> 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'

# get same key from S3
k = bucket.get_key('test_key')
# check MD5
k.md5
>>>  # None
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about what you are doing?  Post some relevant code, perhaps?  Are you using multipart upload or single-part upload?  How are you attempting to find the MD5 for the file that has been uploaded to S3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sort answer is that you should be checking for `k.etag` rather than `k.md5`.

The longer answer is that what boto does when you upload a file is that it computes the MD5 checksum of that file and adds a `Content-MD5` header to the `PUT` request sent to S3.  S3 then computes the MD5 of the file that it receives and compares it to the value of the `Content-MD5` header.  If they do not match, it returns `400 BadDigest` error.  If it does match, it returns a `200 OK` response and includes an `ETag` header in the response.  This etag value should be the same MD5 checksum and boto checks that return value to make sure it matches the MD5 checksum it calculated.

So, boto does a pretty thorough end-to-end integrity check but if you want to check yourself, look for the `ETag` header in the response to the `PUT` or in the response to a `GET` or `HEAD` request on the object.

Also note that this only applies to normal `PUT` operations.  Multi-part uploads are a different beast entirely.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. So just to be certain, does Boto provide any way to compare a local file's checksum with a key's for versioning purposes as opposed to transfer integrity or should I just use the etag?